# jQuery Animation Building Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this animation set up on a site.  However, when you mouseover and mouseout really fast the animation keeps playing even after you stopped doing it (like it builds up animation in the que). I dont really want this to happen, but when I put stop().show etc... it actually doesn't do what I want, because it changes the position of the div (since i didn't allow the animation to finish).

LINK: http://www.everybodywalks.com/main.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#commercialSlide').mouseenter(function() {

          if ($('#commercialBox').is(":hidden"))
               {
                $('#commercialBox').show('slide', { direction: "down" }, 150);
                $('#commercialLink').hide();
                $('#residentialLink').hide();
               } 
               return false;
      });

       $('#commercialBox').mouseleave(function() {

          if ($('#commercialBox').not(":hidden"))
               {
                $('#commercialBox').hide('slide', { direction: "down" }, 150);
                $('#residentialLink').fadeIn(250);
                $('#commercialLink').fadeIn(250);
               }
               return false;
      });

   });
```

commercialBox is the RED box that pops over the link. commercialSlide is the link ID. commercialLink is the div containing the link. I might consolidate the last two, but at this point I just want to get this working.

Comment: Can you provide your html markups?

Comment: Link added to original post with stop(true,true) but when you mouseover and over and then leave your mouse on the div, it loops various times)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the animation queue with `stop()`.

Replace

```
$('#commercialBox').show(..
```

with

```
$('#commercialBox').stop().show(
```

and replace

```
$('#commercialBox').hide(
```

with

```
$('#commercialBox').stop().hide(
```

More reading: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: http://www.everybodywalks.com/main.php<-- this is the page -- so you guys see what I mean.

Comment: I tried that as well and it would change the position of the div animating because I essentially stopped the animation halfway through. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
.stop(true, true)
```

The first parameter will clear all animations from the animation queue, and the second one will complete the current animation immediately. See [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an 'intent' timer to prevent the menu opening accidentally, which should alleviate most of the problem:

```
   var commercial_timer;
   $('#commercialSlide').live('mouseenter',function()
    {

        // We create a slight delay so the menu only opens when the user holds the mouse over
        // the button for a brief moment. Simply moving the cursor over and past the button
        // should not open the menu
        commercial_timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
                $('#commercialBox').show('slide', { direction: 'down' }, 150);
                $('#commercialLink').hide();
                $('#residentialLink').hide();
        },200);

    }); // End mouseenter listener


    // Clear the mouseenter timeout and close the menu if it is open, when the user exits the menu
    $('#commercialSlide, #commercialBox').live('mouseleave',function()
    {
        clearTimeout(commercial_timer);
        if($('#commercialBox').is(':visible'))
        {
                $('#commercialBox').hide('slide', { direction: "down" }, 150);
                $('#residentialLink').fadeIn(250);
                $('#commercialLink').fadeIn(250);
        }
    });
```